# ZPL: Multiple textboxes under each other

Tags: zpl

I would like to print a label with multiple text boxes (something like`^FB600,3,0,c,0`) under each other. The text boxes need to have different fonts and each of them might have variable number of rows.

The issue is how to position these two textblocks under each other so that they don't overlap.

To demonstrate the problem, I use this tool: http://labelary.com/viewer.html

Please try following code:

```
^XA

^FO0,0
^CF0,50
^FB600,4,0,c,0
^FDLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Etiam egestas wisi a erat. Fusce tellus.
^FS

^FO0,300 
^CF0,40
^FB600,3,0,c,0
^FDNulla quis diam. Curabitur ligula sapien, pulvinar a vestibulum quis, facilisis vel sapien. In convallis.
^FS

^XZ
```

The problem is the `^FO0,300` as it is absolute, I need to position the second block according to the first one.

Comment: There should be a way to add a break line or newline. How i can't remember i would have to reread the docs again.

Comment: There is, but there is no way of changing the font.

Comment: Are you doing change font after ^FB or before ? try doing it after. ZPL is one of those tweak till you get it language :(

Comment: I tried this: https://gist.github.com/knyttl/82b6b83f0509a913795feb4cb249d0d5 - changing the size inside the block, but it does not work :/